# db2 create procedure using razor

Tags: db2, procedure

I am using RazorSQL tool to work with DB2. I try to create procedure which contains if table not exist statement.

the problem I am having is that if table doesn't exist it procedure has to execute create table statements.
trying co create a procedure returns error (syntax error), like it can not execute more then only create table statement.

example:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE KLEMENTEST.create_table 
()
LANGUAGE SQL
MODIFIES SQL DATA
--READS SQL DATA
--CONTAINS SQL
begin atomic
 if (not exists(select 'A' from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'KLEMENTEST' and       tabname='bendeldoba')) then
 create table klementest.bendeldoba (
    bdd_id_bdd           INTEGER                not null,
    bdd_naziv            VARCHAR(128)           not null,
    bdd_mesecev          INTEGER                not null default 0,
    bdd_prispevki        INTEGER,
    bdd_procent          numeric,
    bdd_racuni           INTEGER,
    bdd_datvpisa         DATE                   not null,
    bdd_vpisal_uporabnik INTEGER                not null default 0
 );
 alter table klementest.bendeldoba add constraint P_Key_1 primary key (bdd_id_bdd);
 end if;
 end
```

alter table is causing the problems. If I comment it it works, also trying co execute smth like

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE KLEMENTEST.create_table 
    ()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    --READS SQL DATA
    --CONTAINS SQL
    begin atomic
 if (not exists(select 'A' from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'KLEMENTEST' and tabname='bendeldoba')) then
 crete view def_schema.view1 as select * from sometable;
 crete view def_schema.view2 as select * from someothertable;
 end if;
 end
```

it works

where is the "syntax error" problem with my first create procedure query??

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DB2, SQL stored procedures are bound statically in the database.  This means that any static SQL statements (i.e. ones that you don't execute using `PREPARE`/`EXECUTE` or `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`) will be checked and compiled when you create the stored procedure.

Therefore, the error occurs because when DB2 checks the `ALTER TABLE` statement to validity, the KLEMENTEST.BENDELDOBA does not yet exist.

The best way to resolve this is to make the `ALTER TABLE` statement a dynamic statement:

```
declare vSQL varchar(1024);

-- portion of procedure that creates the table... 

set vSQL = 'alter table ...';
execute immediate vSQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some additional "setters", to declare where atomic procedure starts and ends
The code looks like this now

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE KLEMENTEST.create_table 
()
LANGUAGE SQL
ap: begin  atomic
declare vsql varchar(1024) ;
set vSQL = 'alter table KLEMENTEST.avtvrsteplacilapod add constraint P_Key_1 primary key (avp_id_avp)';

 if (not exists(select 'A' from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'KLEMENTEST' and tabname='AVTVRSTEPLACILAPOD')) then

 create table KLEMENTEST.avtvrsteplacilapod (
   avp_id_avp           INTEGER                not null,
  avp_vrsteplacila     INTEGER                not null,
avp_naziv            VARCHAR(64)            not null,
avp_skupinevrpl      INTEGER                not null ,
avp_avtvrplmestovprog INTEGER               ,
avp_postrm           SMALLINT               not null,
avp_upostzap         SMALLINT               not null
```

);

```
 execute immediate vsql;
 end if ;
 end ap
```